# Json array of objects in php

Tags: php, arrays, json, arraylist

this is the json that my code produces

```
{
"aaa":1,
"b":2,
"c":3,
"d":4,
"e":5,
"fff":{"a":11111,"b":222222,"c":33333,"d":444454,"e":55555555}
}
```

and this is the code

```
<?php
$c = array('a' => 11111, 'b' => 222222, 'c' => 33333, 'd' => 444454, 'e' => 55555555 );
$arr = array('aaa' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5 , 'fff'=>$c);
echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

but I want to have some structure like this

```
{
"aaa":1,
"b":2,
"c":3,
"d":4,
"e":5,
"fff":{"a":11111,"b":222222,"c":33333,"d":444454,"e":55555555},
"last":[
      {
        "id": 8817,
        "loc": "NEW YORK CITY"
      },
      {
        "id": 2873,
        "loc": "UNITED STATES"
      },
      {
        "id": 1501,
        "loc": "NEW YORK STATE"
      }
    ]
}
```

I am new in json and php and I need this fast so I do not have time to read about this json structure... So please if someone know how to add this last element please provide some php code.

Thanks,

Comment: Uhm... just add a `"last"` array to your `$arr`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Take the "json-encoded" string and pass it to json_decode()
- assign the return value to a variable
- pass that variable to var_export() to get a "php-encoded" string representation of the data.

e.g.

```
<?php
$json = '{
"aaa":1,
"b":2,
"c":3,
"d":4,
"e":5,
"fff":{"a":11111,"b":222222,"c":33333,"d":444454,"e":55555555},
"last":[
      {
        "id": 8817,
        "loc": "NEW YORK CITY"
      },
      {
        "id": 2873,
        "loc": "UNITED STATES"
      },
      {
        "id": 1501,
        "loc": "NEW YORK STATE"
      }
    ]
}';


$php = json_decode($json, true);
echo var_export($php);
```

prints

```
array (
  'aaa' => 1,
  'b' => 2,
  'c' => 3,
  'd' => 4,
  'e' => 5,
  'fff' => 
  array (
    'a' => 11111,
    'b' => 222222,
    'c' => 33333,
    'd' => 444454,
    'e' => 55555555,
  ),
  'last' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'id' => 8817,
      'loc' => 'NEW YORK CITY',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'id' => 2873,
      'loc' => 'UNITED STATES',
    ),
    2 => 
    array (
      'id' => 1501,
      'loc' => 'NEW YORK STATE',
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: Damned, I was writing the resulting php code manualy! Clever use of var_export :-)

Just to make the answer clearer, 
an array with not numeric keys is translated to an object (with {}) and a numeric keys array to an array (with []).

Comment: I do not understand how this answers the OP?

Comment: @Damien An array with *continuous* numeric keys. `array(1 => 'foo', 0 => 'bar')` will be encoded as an object as well (at least in some versions of PHP, AFAIR).

Comment: nickb, I assumed (wild-guessing-mode) the op had a some javascript object literal as a template and wanted a congruent php template. And via json_decode/var_export one can create such a php template. Not rocket science, but ...